# Where to put "immer"? Wenn und als

Tags: grammar-identification

I'm doing an exercise "Bilden Sie Temporalsätze mit wenn und als". With the following given words, I shall write a sentence: immer, er, mit, die Arbeit, fertig, sein (präteritum), er, in, das Kino, gehen (präteritum).

This is my answer:

Wenn er immer mit die Arbeit fertig war, ging er ins Kino.

But I can't tell whether the place of "immer" is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has to read either

> **Immer wenn** er mit *der* Arbeit fertig war, ging er ins Kino.

or

> Wenn er mit *der* Arbeit fertig war, ging er **immer** ins Kino.
>
> Er ging **immer** ins Kino, wenn er mit *der* Arbeit fertig war.

(Please note *die Arbeit* becomes *der Arbeit* when put into *Dativ*, as required by the verb *fertig sein mit + Dativ*.)

---

Why put *immer* in front? That is because **immer wenn** is a fixed phrase meaning *each time*.

And why alternatively put *immer* into the main clause? In German the focus of a sentence is on the first, then the last thing in it. When you put *immer wenn* at the front of a sentence, you put very much attention to that fact. You may not want this and put another thing into focus.